# How do I support plugins for a node.js command line utility?

Tags: node.js, plugins, npm

I am writing a utility (written in Node.js) which will be invoked from the command line. The specifics don't matter, but the functionality can be broken out into separate unrelated modules, each of which can contribute to the final result independently.

Eg, I can invoke:

```
npm install -g myutil   #installs modulea and moduleb
myutil                  #invokes said modules
```

Assuming there exists modules `modulea` and `moduleb`. Currently, all such modules are bundled as dependencies of `myutil`, but in an ideal world, I'd like to split them out and have them be installed separately, allowing for other people to write modules

```
npm install -g myutil-contrib-modulec
```

And then detect `myutil-contrib-modulec` at runtime and use it like everything else. However, there are some questions around it:

1. Is this a good idea?
2. Is there a supported way to do this? The FAQ suggests that global modules are supposed to be completely separate, but I imagine this is a reasonable use case.
3. If it's not supported at all, are there any alternatives? Eg, one alternative I could think of is to force the user to install the extra modules locally per project (but, that's not a great solution IMO).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answer doesn't really answer the question, so for future visitors I will post my actual solution.

I ended up nixing the globally installed plugin idea. Instead, I'm keeping the plugins bundled with the tool. To support custom plugins, I'm allowing the user to install them locally.

The code that loads the plugins follows similar [rules as node itself](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders), so if you really want to install a plugin in a global manner, just put it higher up on the directory tree.

Comment: could you please share a link to your tool for the implementation reference?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [liftoff](https://www.npmjs.com/package/liftoff) which can help with the global/local CLI issue. Maybe you use it, but maybe you just read it for ideas. I think the current strategy is if you must install something globally, make it just a tiny `myutil` wrapper package which should just locate the local one inside `some-users-project/node_modules/myutil`. There's no reason for the plugins to be installed globally as they won't be directly run on the command line, so those should go locally only.

> I could think of is to force the user to install the extra modules locally per project (but, that's not a great solution IMO).

My opinion here is `npm -g` is generally a terrible idea. It's sad that people are unable to adjust their PATH environment variable or set up a shell alias, but I can understand why you want to install `myutil` globally. Wanting all the plugins installed globally is probably misguided. BUT that depends on exactly what `myutil` does and how strongly coupled it is to the project that is using it. From my perspective, I want everything local, including node itself. I want my projects independent. I don't want to update `myutil` for project A and have project B break as a side effect.

Comment: There's a few details that I elided from my question since they're not really relevant. 1. This is an internal tool that does some basic editorial checking of sites that we build. 2. The global plugins thing was to make it easy to use, because otherwise no one will use it.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases you could use [Oclif](https://oclif.io). The plugins will be installed globally on the users computer. [Here](https://oclif.io/docs/plugins) they explain how a user can build plugins for the CLIs using it.

Heroku CLI uses Oclif. See their [developing a plugin](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/developing-cli-plugins), to see how they handle it.